# Issue when scrolling through a tableview while feeding the cells with external data

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uikit

I am trying to recreate a browser within an app. I created a section where the user could add his/her favourite websites, so they can be displayed in a tableview. I am using a third-party api to get and display the title, description and the favicon of the selected website. This is how it works. There are two view controllers, the first one the browser itself and the other one the favourite tableview controller where the user can see its favourite websites. When the user taps in the "+" sign in the first view controller, the current url is saved in an array with UserDefaults (I encountered some problems saving it with Codable) and then in the second view controller, the tableview is populated in a for-loop with each url that the user has saved.

The problem is the following:

When the user has already added various websites, it has to scroll to find all of what he/she saved. However every tableview cell gets recycled so it gets loaded again every time the user scrolls up and down.

This is when the user first opens the favourite section
[image: This is when the user first opens the favourite section]

When the user scrolls

[image: When the user scrolls]

When the user scrolls up to a tableview cell that allegedly already loaded up
[image: When the user scrolls up to a tableview cell that allegedly already loaded up]

The two arrays that are used are the following:

```
var modifiedURLS = defaults.object(forKey: "modifiedURLS") as! [String]

var nonModifiedURLS = defaults.object(forKey: "nonModifiedURLS") as! [String]
```

I am using two arrays because the api that I'm using (SwiftLinkPreview) only works when the requested url is a normal one (nothing else after .com)
so I am saving a modified url to access the Title, description and favicon properties with this api, and a nonModified url that stores exactly the url that the user wanted to save

The code when the tableviewcontroller is populated is the following:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "favoritesCell", for: indexPath) as! BookmarkTableViewCell

    let slp = SwiftLinkPreview(session: .shared, workQueue: SwiftLinkPreview.defaultWorkQueue, responseQueue: DispatchQueue.main, cache: DisabledCache.instance)

    cell.titleWebLabel.text = "Loading title..."
    cell.descriptionWebLabel.text = "Loading description..."
    cell.urlLabel.text = nonModifiedURLS[indexPath.row]

    for _ in 0...modifiedURLS.count - 1 {
        // The following is an asynchronous request
        slp.preview(modifiedURLS[indexPath.row], onSuccess: { result in
            let titleIndex = result.index(forKey: SwiftLinkResponseKey.title) as! Dictionary<SwiftLinkResponseKey, Any>.Index
            let title:String = result[titleIndex].value as! String
            cell.titleWebLabel.text = title

            let descriptionIndex = result.index(forKey: SwiftLinkResponseKey.description) as! Dictionary<SwiftLinkResponseKey, Any>.Index
            let description:String = result[descriptionIndex].value as! String

            cell.descriptionWebLabel.text = description

            let favIconIndex = result.index(forKey: SwiftLinkResponseKey.image) as! Dictionary<SwiftLinkResponseKey, Any>.Index
            let favIcon = result[favIconIndex].value
            cell.favIconImageView.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: "\(favIcon as! String)"))
        },
             onError: { error in print("\(error)")})
    }

    return cell
}
```

The project can be found in the following GitHub link: https://github.com/francisc112/IssueBrowser

Comment: What you need to do is maintain array of class which store information which you getting from apis. And store into it. So next time when same cell get loaded what you need to do check in array if data exist if exist then get from array else get from apis.

Comment: I already tried that, however the request is asynchronous so when I try to store what's been given by the api to a model, its already to late and it gives me a result of nil. Is there anyway I could make it  a synchronous request?